# XUnit custom data attribute executes for every test

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xunit, xunit.net

I have a custom data attribute in xUnit.

```
public class MyTest : DataAttribute
{
    private readonly int _x;
    private readonly int _y;

    public MyTest(int x, int y)
    {
        _x = x;
        _y = y;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<object[]> GetData(MethodInfo testMethod)
    {
        return new[] { new object[] { _x, _y } };
    }
}
```

Then i have two tests

```
    [Theory]
    [MyTest(100, 200)]
    public void Test1(int x, int y)
    {
        var r = x * y;
        Assert.Equal(20000, r);
    }


    [Theory]
    [MyTest(300, 400)]
    public void Test2(int x, int y)
    {
        var r = x * y;
        Assert.Equal(120000, r);
    }
```

Then i put breakpoint in `MyTest` attribute's GetData() method. And then  in Test Explorer i right clicked on `Test1` and click debug selected tests.

When i do that i notice `MyTest` attribute get executed twice, for `Test1` and`Test2`. I am not sure why its also getting executed for the `Test2`?

If i have more tests with `MyTest` attributes, then it executes for each of those tests.
Is there any way to disable this behavior?

Comment: I suspect that "run this test" starts of by gathering all the information for tests available, then matching "what I've asked for" against "what's available".

Comment: `MyTest` attribute is a metadata, which will be gathered before running the test and applied for the tests to run.

Comment: This overhead becomes quite burdensome as a test suite grows since each test will always pay the sum cost of all tests decorated with such an attribute. I don't recall the NUnit test runner having such behavior.

Answer (score 2):

By default, xUnit enables enumeration during discovery of any custom data attribute that inherits directly from `Xunit.Sdk.DataAttribute`. You can make this enumeration configurable for your custom data attribute by adding the following to your implementation.

```
[DataDiscoverer("MyNamespace.MyTestDataAttribute+Discoverer", "MyAssemblyFullyQualifiedName")]
public class MyTestDataAttribute : DataAttribute
{
    protected class Discoverer : DataDiscoverer
    {
        public override bool SupportsDiscoveryEnumeration(IAttributeInfo dataAttribute, IMethodInfo testMethod)
        {
            return dataAttribute.GetNamedArgument<bool>(nameof(MyTestDataAttribute.SupportsDiscoveryEnumeration));
        }
    }

    private readonly int _x;
    private readonly int _y;

    /// <summary>
    ///     Returns <c>false</c> if the data attribute wants to skip enumerating data during discovery. This will cause the
    ///     theory to yield a single test case for all data, and the data discovery will be during test execution instead of
    ///     discovery.
    /// </summary>
    public bool SupportsDiscoveryEnumeration { get; set; }

    public MyTest(int x, int y)
    {
        _x = x;
        _y = y;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<object[]> GetData(MethodInfo testMethod)
    {
        return new[] { new object[] { _x, _y } };
    }
}
```

This configures xUnit to skip data enumeration by default for your custom data attribute during the discovery phase, and instead delays that discovery until the execution phase.

Therefore, you would simply implement your tests as normal, and opt-in only those tests you wish to be discovered (for whatever reason) before test execution.

```
[Theory]
[MyTest(100, 200)]
public void Test1(int x, int y)
{
    int r = x * y;
    Assert.Equal(20000, r);
}

[Theory]
[MyTest(300, 400, SupportsDiscoveryEnumeration = true)]
public void Test2(int x, int y)
{
    int r = x * y;
    Assert.Equal(120000, r);
}
```